# Laravel session expires immediately (Laravel 5.5)

Tags: php, laravel, session, authentication, logging

I have created my custom model to log in the users. I am using sqlite as database. "users" table has "id" column and I am not using eloquent so I have changed the driver as "database" and table as "users" in auth.config file.

My index controller checks the user if it is logged in. If not, redirects to the login page. Once the login form is submitted (ajax call), if the user enter wrong username or password, it gets error message in a modal telling it has entered wrong credentials. If the username and password are true, it redirects to the index page. But because the user is not assumed as logged in, again it redirects to the login page. Also I tried to echo the id of the user after the successful attempt (without redirecting), and it displayed without problem. But after visiting the index page, I am redirected to login page again.

I have tried to add session and display it so if I call the following code;

```
session()->put('foo', 'bar');
echo session()->get('foo');
```

"bar" is echoed on the page. But if I echo the session on another page (without putting a new session because I have already added), "bar" is not echoed on the page.

Also note that no files are stored in "storage/framework/sessions" folder.

Session type is file and lifetime is 720.I have also tried "cookie" and "database". The same problem occured with "cookie" but I got "database driver cannot be used" exception with "database" driver (I have successfully migrated the necessary tables).

Also the website is on localhost (Windows 10). So I do not think folder permissions can be a problem. Also I have another Laravel (older version - it must be 5.4 I think) on the same pc and it is working without problem. Both are using php 7 and nginx server.

Comment: Just a side note - 419 "your session has expired" can also happen if you forget to put `@csrf` inside your form in the login blade :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I have found my problem. I had created a custom ServiceProvider and defined custom routes to create modular system. Because I tried to "include" route files here, new laravel routing system acted it as api routes. So sessions were not available.

Now I have changed my code to:

```
Route::middleware('web')->group($route_file);
```

and routes are behaved as web routes and sessions are working.

Hope to see this helps others having this issue.

Comment: Can you please provide example content for the route file content? I am in a similar situation now

Comment: This issue is not about the route file itself, but if you want to use your custom route file. You can register a new route file in a service provider (you may use AppServiceProvider of course). Add the code above into the "boot" function. $route_file variable is the path to your custom route file. Just add your routes in this file as usual. You can change middleware from "web" to "api" if you want to use it for api routes. Also you can add "prefix", "name" to the code above as you do in route file. The routes you defined in this file will start with the prefix and name.

Answer (score 1):

Check session configuration on file `config/session.php`.

If your session driver is file, make sure you have permissions on `storage/session` folder with `chmod -R 777 storage`.

Also you can check for `lifetime` and `expire_on_close` configurations on that file to preserve session between requests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have already mentioned about this precautions in my question.